# Stream Observable for just one value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I want to do something like this but just for one value.

```
Stream<bool> get outSubmitValidTwo => Observable.combineLatest3(
  outUf,
  outCidade,
  outTelefone,
  (
    a,
    b,
    c,
  ) =>
      true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean for one value or for one stream?

For single stream use:

```dart
Observable(stream);
```

For single value use:

```dart
Observable.just(value);
```

Comment: it was for one stream. It works fine now. Thank u :)